# Simple Error '(' expected

Tags: java

```
public void displayResults
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
          System.out.printf("Value %d = %.6f\n", i, list[i]);
    }

    System.out.printf("Sum of all values = %0.6f\n", sum);
    System.out.printf("Average of all values = %0.6f\n", average);
    System.out.printf("Largest value = %0.6f\n", largest);
    System.out.printf("Smallest value = %0.6f\n", smallest);
}
```

I am getting the good old `error: '(' expected`

at where the `{` should be, I really don't see whats wrong with what I have. Been staring at this same error for almost a hour. really hoping a new set of eyes can see the issue.

```
public void displayResults
 ==>   {
       for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
       {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void displayResults ()
                           ^^
```

You need to add the parameter list parentheses even if you have no parameters.

Comment: @user1714873 I think it is a good idea to accept this answer.

Comment: MY EDITOR LIED TO ME! lol, thanks for pointing that out, it was so obvious, but I kept staring at the line below that.

Comment: @user1714873 you are welcome! It typically works that way, shows the last point where that bracket might have been valid. So the  arrow means just before this point.